# Python Tkinter Frame Class don't recognise objects

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

class MainApplication(ttk.Frame):
    texty = "text"

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(text=MainApplication.texty, command=self.ev(self))
        self.button1.pack()

    def ev(event, self):
        print(self.button1.text)
```

It calls: 'MainApplication' object has no attribute 'button1'. Why?

Comment: `command=self.ev(self)` tries to run `self.ev(self)` immediately. Also, your `ev` definition is messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your code and not just your MainApplication object error.

1. Initialize the instance with `Tk()` to create the root or main toplevel window.
2. Don't call a class attribute from inside the class by trying to call the class name.
3. Place the `texty` variable inside of the `__init__` part of your class and make it an attribute by putting `self` in front of it.
4. Maintain good indention for code to work properly so make sure your methods are in the class with 4 space indention's.
5. Don't print `self.button1.text` Instead print the attribute value by printing `self.texty`. If you really want to print the text on the button you can use `self.button1['text']` or `self.button1.cget("text")` to accomplish this.
6. Assign your class to a variable so you can interact with its attributes from outside of the class if you need to.
7. `command = slef.ev(self)` is passing 2 self arguments and only requires one. Do `self.ev` instead.

---

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

class MainApplication(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.texty = "text"
        self.parent = parent
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(text = self.texty, command= self.ev)
        self.button1.pack()

    def ev(self):
        print(self.texty) # for printing the value of the attribute
        print(self.button1['text']) # for printing the current text of the button

app = MainApplication(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Just incase you were trying to print the atribute from outside of the class

You can places this outside of the class to see its results.

```
def print_something():
    print(app.texty) # this is why we assign the class to a variable
    print(app.button1['text']) # it allows us to interact with class atributes from outside the class
```

Comment: Clearly the author has not placed all the code. Second if the button text changes how you get it fails.

Comment: It is not necessary to put `root = tkinter.Tk()` before the implementation of the class, it must be placed before the declaration of the instances.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Thanks for pointing out the printing issue. I just assumed the OP wanted to print the texty attribute and was going about it in a strange way.

Comment: I said at the start of the program I did not say before the class. But I could see how that could be confusing.

Comment: @Bobslay: You are welcome. Please select the check box next to the answer that best solved your problem so others will know you have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the command attribute you must pass the name of the function, you should not call the function. In your case self.ev

In addition to get the name of the variable you must use `{your button}['text']` or `{your button}.cget('text')`

Also `def ev(event, self):` is not correct, the commands do not pass any parameter so you just pass the instance: self.

*Note: you must always pass the instance first: `def some_function(self, other params ...)`*

```
class MainApplication(ttk.Frame):
    texty = "text"

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(text=MainApplication.texty, command=self.ev)
        self.button1.pack()

    def ev(self):
        print(self.button1['text']) # or self.button1.cget('text')

root = tkinter.Tk()
w = MainApplication(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "you must use `{your button}['text']` is not quite true. That's one way to do it but it's not the only way to do it. You can also do `print(self.button1.cget("text"))`

Comment: Thank's very much!!